# Notification Reminder in Tabbar Environment

Tags: iphone, sdk, notifications, local

I've got a question regarding displaying local notification reminders inside the application. I think the problem lies with the view controller.

here's the code I have so far:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    UIViewController *viewController1, *viewController2;
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        viewController1 = [[Number1ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Number1ViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];
        viewController2 = [[SettingsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SettingsViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];
    } else {
        viewController1 = [[Number1ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Number1ViewController_iPad" bundle:nil];
        viewController2 = [[SettingsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SettingsViewController_iPad" bundle:nil];
    }
    self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:viewController1, viewController2, nil];


        UILocalNotification *notification = [launchOptions objectForKey:

                                             UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];


        if (notification) {

            NSString *stringReminder = [notification.userInfo 

                                      objectForKey:@"TextforReminder"];

            [viewController showReminder:stringReminder];


        }


    }



    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];


    self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

or:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification {

    UIApplicationState state = [application applicationState];

    if (state == UIApplicationStateInactive) {

        application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];


        NSString *stringReminder = [notification.userInfo

                                  objectForKey:@"TextforReminder"];

        [viewController showReminder:stringReminder];

    }

}
```

However I am getting errors regarding the view Controller. Use of undeclared identifier 'viewController'. I understand that this is becuase there is no view controller, however I don't unterstand how I have to achieve, that the Reminder is shown in the process.

Thanks a lot for your help, I am not getting further in this problem.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your warning is trying to tell you the problem in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` is in.

```
if (notification) {
    NSString *stringReminder = [notification.userInfo objectForKey:@"TextforReminder"];
    [viewController showReminder:stringReminder];
}
application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
```

`UIViewController` has no method named `showReminder:`, so I assume it's in your subclass of one of your `UIViewController` subclasses.

You need to do two things,

1) Replace '`viewController`' with either '`viewController1`' or '`viewController2`' whichever has the method `showReminder:`

2) You need to wait until these viewControllers are actually on screen before presenting more views on top of them. So move the block above to after the `[self.window makeKeyAndVisible]` but before `return YES`.

Edited as comment says `SettingViewController` will have the `showReminder:` method;

As far as the problem receiving `LocalNotifications` while the app is running. If your app is simple then maybe just replace '`viewController`' with:

`(SettingsViewController *)[self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1]`

Since in your code you add it as the second element of the `viewControllers` property.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply! / I have done what you said, but I am still getting two errors: in the first part I am getting: Receiver type 'UIViewController' for instance message does not declare a method with selector 'showReminder:' and the error in the second part is: No known instance method for selector 'showReminder:' // I much appreciate your help, I know that I am a newbie, but I am trying to learn as much as possible, but sometimes its not possible without help from professionals :) Cheers

Comment: or do I have to create the showReminder: method myself in the respective view controllers??

Comment: Does either `Number1ViewController` or `SettingsViewController` have a `showReminder:` method? Since they are your classes only you would know. Also are you getting these warnings in both `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` & `didReceiveLocalNotification:`?

Comment: you must think I am completely stupid ;-) am I getting this right, I "set a notification" and it fires, once it comes back from background, it triggers didReceiveLocalNotification and in there (or in the respective View Controller) I'll have to manually display an AlertView? // in SettingsViewController i'll define a showReminder method in which I then display an alertView? //Thanks again for your kind and patient help! That is much appreciated!

Comment: Basically Yes. I just want to make clear that your initial approach of handling a LocalNotification in both `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` & `didReceiveLocalNotification:` is correct. If the user taps to accept the notification and enter your app, it will enter through ONE of those two methods. Depending on if it's in the background or not running.

Comment: You are a star! I will do that try that right away! And will let you know if I succeeded, but thanks to your guidance it was easy to solve the problem!

Comment: Thanks for your help, the alert showed, but I have to set all the different kinds of notificaitons up correctly now :) A lot to do! Cheers